# edit data grid without events of datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a class that has a double variable. I want to enter the number entered in the data grade cells without using data grade events when I enter a number after press enter send value in data grid cell to variable d with a function or method inside the class.

XAML code :

```
<StackPanel>
<DataGrid   Height="120" Name="Grid" Margin="5" />
<Button  Margin="10" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" >Click</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

CS code:

```
   namespace WpfApp4
{
    {
        private double d ;
        public   double D
        {
            set
            {
                d = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return d;
            }
        } 

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return D.ToString();
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MyClass myClass1=new MyClass();
        MyClass myClass2=new MyClass();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Double", typeof(MyClass)));
            dt.NewRow();
            dt.Rows.Add(myClass1);
            dt.Rows.Add(myClass2);
            Grid.ItemsSource= dt.DefaultView;
        }
        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Value Datatable rows is:" + dt.Rows[i]["Double"]);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Value D is :" + myClass1.D);        
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You rae doing things Old School. Read about MVVM pattern and DataBinding.

Comment: Bare minimum you need is Data Binding & INotifyPropertyChanged even if you do not use MVVM pattern.

Comment: I have read but do not know how to get datagrid values ​​without using the datagrid event through the method inside the class

Comment: If you can help, thank you